# How to define inputs that are the result of an iteration? Python ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, iteration

The script (helped by @BERA and badly added to by me *completely new to coding) iterates through the fields in a polygon attribute table to convert to a temporary raster (for different scenarios in the cost analysis) and then do a cost analysis on each raster.  I need the resulting accumulated cost surface to be the input of the next part of the analysis – namely set null values and the resulting raster to be the input for summarize zones  - and repeated for each cost surface.

How do I define the inputs and outputs please (of null value and summarise zones)?

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

 # Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Set overwrite option
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Local variables:
habitat = "D:\gis_data\habitat.shp"
fodyrange_current = "D:\gis_data\fodyrange_current.shp"
AQ = "D:\gis_data\AQ.shp"
R_fody_exp1= ' D:\gis_data\model_outputs\raster_f_1'
backlink_fmaq = ""
nullc_f1 = "D:\gis_data\model_outputs\nullc_f1"
zone_fody_exp1 = "D:\gis_data\model_outputs\zone_fody_exp1"

fieldlist=['fody_exp1','fody_exp2','fody_exp3','fody_exp4'] #extend/edit to include all your fields

for item in fieldlist: #For each field specified in fieldlist perform all below:
arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(in_features=habitat, field=item, out_raster=r'in_memory\tempraster')
#Dont know what you want to do next, cost distance?:
outCostDistance = CostDistance(AQ, r'in_memory\tempraster')
outCostDistance.save(os.path.join(r'D:\gis_data\model_outputs','R_'+item)) #The outputs will be named after field, for example R_fody_exp1
#and so on...

# I don’t know how to set the input in the following so that it iterates through all the outputs of the cost analysis

# Process: Set Null
arcpy.gp.SetNull_sa(R_fody_exp1, R_fody_exp1, nullc_f1, "\"value\" = 0")

# Process: Zonal Statistics as Table
arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(AQ, "id", nullc_f1, zone_f_1, "DATA", "ALL")
```

This is the ModelBuilder model exported as python (sorry about long pathnames)- but does not include any iterations.  It is necessary to iterate through the fields in an an attribute table to get the values to be used as cell values when converting to raster in the first step in this process and then use the outputs in the rest of the process.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Set Geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "C:\\Users\\willow\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb"
arcpy.env.snapRaster = "scores_fody_m"
arcpy.env.extent = "534630.586094391 7813776.96082858 552599.503136767 7825252.24043838"
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\willow\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb"


# Local variables:
habitat = "habitat"
fodyrange_current = "fodyrange_current"
AQ = "AQ"
hab_sn_1 =         
"D:\\gis_data\\rodrigues\\Rod_analysis\\iterate_model\\hab_ras\\hab_sn1"
dist_sn_1 =
```

"D:\gis_data\rodrigues\Rod_analysis\iterate_model\dis_raster\dist_sn_1"
    backlink_fmaq = ""
    nullcost_sn_1 =

"D:\gis_data\rodrigues\Rod_analysis\iterate_model\setnull_cost_r\nullcost_sn_1"
    zone_sn_1 =

"D:\gis_data\rodrigues\Rod_analysis\iterate_model\zonal_tables\zone_sn_1"

```
# Process: Polygon to Raster
arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion(habitat, "warb_mean", hab_sn_1, "CELL_CENTER", "NONE", "20")

# Process: Cost Distance
arcpy.gp.CostDistance_sa(fodyrange_current, hab_sn_1, dist_sn_1, "", backlink_fmaq)

# Process: Set Null
arcpy.gp.SetNull_sa(dist_sn_1, dist_sn_1, nullcost_sn_1, "\"value\" = 0")

# Process: Zonal Statistics as Table
arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(AQ, "id", nullcost_sn_1, zone_sn_1, "DATA", "ALL")
```

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all your syntax is messed up.  The for loop will not run without an indent.

To answer one of your questions, you can use list comprehension to create a second list with the same names as the outputs from your for loop.

```
fieldlist=['fody_exp1','fody_exp2','fody_exp3','fody_exp4'] 

# run cost analysis

prefix = 'R_'
cost_output = [prefix + x for x in Fieldlist]
# cost_output is now a list the same as all your outputs from the cost analysis

# then you will run a for loop for the following two steps
for output in cost_output:
    arcpy.gp.SetNull_sa(output, output, nullc_f1, "\"value\" = 0"
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(AQ, "id", nullc_f1, zone_f_1, "DATA", "ALL")
```

Comment: So sorry @simon.y - do I substitute the x ? cant get it to work - how does it know to use output of polygon to raster temporary raster as input to cost analysis? Sorry I have tried so many combinations and looked at lots of examples and help but cannot get it to work - thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You are actually asking two questions.  I answered the question relating to the output of the cost path analysis,  leading into the set null and zonal statistics.  But, I did make a mistake. I did not notice the outCostDistance.save, so what i told you would not work because it is not creating a complete path name to the save location (list comprehensions could be used to do this if that is what you decide to do).

Comment: The other question I am not most knowledgeable on cost path analysis.  I would suggest if you are having many problems write down (or model)  all of the geoprocessing steps in order and the location of the input/output for each step.  Then you know what outputs need to feed into what inputs and where you need to create a variable or a list of variables in your script.  I would also suggest putting all of your data in one folder or set of folders (GDB?) then use environment settings to define the path of all of your outputs to that folder location.  Sorry I cant help more.

Comment: Set current workspace:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/current-workspace.htm

Comment: The code does the first two parts without a problem - but how to specify feeding those cost outputs into null values is the problem - So I have to create a full path name to the save location in the outCostDistance.save? where does this part go? There are going to be 100 or more for each run of this script.  I can see the x for x to create a list makes sense - if only I could understand properly how to use it.  I have a model builder that runs the whole process fine - but model builder will not iterate through fields in an attribute table for the firstpart -hence trying to do it all in python.

Comment: I have added the code from model builder incase it helps? Thanks so much.